# Material.io fonts arrow_right not showing

Tags: css, fonts

All the material icons are showing in the pseudo before after except **arrow_right and arrow_left** not sure why they are not getting displayed 
I have created a pen
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZPQQaR.

this

```
p:after{
                content: 'arrow_right';
                font-family: 'Material Icons';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be an issue from the page library. You should report it.

You can use this link instead, it's from the official page.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
  rel="stylesheet">
```